# Play framework 2.2.1 multi-select with comma delimited strings

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, playframework

Hoping the play masters can come to my rescue again. I have a java play model with getters and setters:

```
public String _tvAccess;
@JsonProperty("TvAccess")
public String getTvAccess() {
   return this._tvAccess;
}
@JsonProperty("TvAccess")
public void setTvAccess(String _tvAccess) {
   this._tvAccess = _tvAccess;
}
```

and the following scala view:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span12">
@helper.select(reportForm("TvAccess"),
options = options(picklists.getSafeValuesFor("picklistfor_tvaccess")),
'_overrideModel -> formOverrider.getFieldOverride("TvAccess"),
class -> "form-field-input ",
'multiple -> "multiple",
'_label -> "TV Access:"
)(fldConstructor, Lang(lang))
</div>
</div>
```

My problem is that the multiselect needs to be saved as a comma OR pipe delimited string (not an array), and read back as the same .. so when we do a POST, it sends a string to the db, and when we do a GET, the string is serialized back and the appropriate options that were selected as displayed. I have tried a few "soutions" but cant get anything to work appropriately? It currently tries to save the data as TvAccess[] and even if I get it to be a string using js `("$(field).val().join(',')")`, there isnt a neat way to get it back to the view. Hoping you guys can help?

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to let folks know how I fixed this. IN the controller, before the scala file is bound to the model, I wrote a method to take the data from the array and convert it to a comma delimited string. And I also created our own multiselect.scala.html file that took a comma delimited string and converted it to a multiselect. Hope this helps someone else that encounters a similar issue.